# How to Exclude duplicates of CHVRSN and have maximum value for CHVRSN?

Tags: sql, db2, max

How to exclude duplicate value of CHVRSN AND the maximum value of CHVRSN must remain.
CHVRSN is in table : WRPDT.WSCLHP B

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.REGN ,C.SVDC,A.DELR,C.NAME, A.PANO, A.VIN,A.UDAT AS UPDATE_DATE ,A.WONO AS PAID_DATE,B.CHWONO AS DATE_2 ,B.CHAJDT AS ADJ_DATE,
CASE
WHEN PW = '4' THEN 'A'
WHEN PW = '4' THEN 'A'
WHEN PW = '0' THEN 'IP'
WHEN PW = '3' THEN 'IP'
WHEN PW = '2' THEN 'R'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END AS STATUS,
CHVRSN, CHSB

FROM WRPDT.WPPWP A

LEFT OUTER JOIN WRPDT.WSCLHP B
ON A.PWF = B.CHF
AND A.PWLR=B.CDLR
AND A.WONO=B.CHNO

LEFT OUTER JOIN DLPDT.DRDMFP C
ON A.PWDLR = C.DMLR

WHERE SYS2 = '20'
and cdat > 20180809
AND EAMT > 1000
and pw not in ('90', '95', '05') 

AND EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM CADAT.CCAMP WHERE CMIN=PVIN AND (CMCAMP IN ('953')))

ORDER BY 3, 5
```

Comment: A screenshot of the result or the result itself can help understand a little better i think.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Try a sub-select with a group by the join columns and MAX(CHVRSN). Also removing the DISTINCT is good practice; de-duplicating in sub-selects and/or via GROUP BY shows you understand your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this I would suggest

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.REGN ,C.SVDC,A.DELR,C.NAME, A.PANO, A.VIN,A.UDAT AS UPDATE_DATE ,A.WONO AS PAID_DATE,B.CHWONO AS DATE_2 ,B.CHAJDT AS ADJ_DATE,
CASE
WHEN PW = '4' THEN 'A'
WHEN PW = '4' THEN 'A'
WHEN PW = '0' THEN 'IP'
WHEN PW = '3' THEN 'IP'
WHEN PW = '2' THEN 'R'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END AS STATUS,
CHVRSN, CHSB

FROM WRPDT.WPPWP A

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM WRPDT.WSCLHP
    WHERE CHVRSN IN (SELECT MAX(CHVRSN) FROM WRPDT.WSCLHP) 
    ) AS B
ON A.PWF = B.CHF
AND A.PWLR=B.CDLR
AND A.WONO=B.CHNO

LEFT OUTER JOIN DLPDT.DRDMFP C
ON A.PWDLR = C.DMLR

WHERE SYS2 = '20'
and cdat > 20180809
AND EAMT > 1000
and pw not in ('90', '95', '05') 

AND EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM CADAT.CCAMP WHERE CMIN=PVIN AND (CMCAMP IN ('953')))

ORDER BY 3, 5
```

BTW your code could be clearer. Not all column references are qualified so I've only included those explicitly needed in the sub-select.

Comment: Thank you for the solution,but this does not give me the result. It is not filtering out the maximum values. I am using QMF tool and database is DB2

Comment: You need to explain your question better. You said "the maximum value of CHVRSN must remain." .. so I took the MAX() of that column. If you want something different, you need to be more clear about what that is

Comment: I am sorry. In the previous comment I  meant that the values other than maximum value are not filtering out.

Comment: Please edit your original question, or maybe delete this question and try again with a must clearer request that includes say some sample data, or a _minimal reproducable question_

Comment: In the meantime, I've edited my answer, guessing what you might mean by "the values other than maximum value are not filtering out."